# How can a native speaker understand Mank is asking question without seeing subtitles?

Tags: meaning

Mank speaks about Modern Quixote movie character:

> Mank: Love him enough to make him president. But they won't, and they
> don't. How do you suppose that could happen? **Could it be because, in
> their hearts, they know that he values power over people?**
> Disillusioned in Congress, he authors not one single piece of
> legislation in two terms.

How can a native speaker understand Mank is asking question without seeing subtitles?

Comment: In spoken English, [questions, especially yes/no questions, usually end with a rising tone](https://rachelsenglish.com/questions-intonation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Could* is an auxiliary verb which was placed at the beginning. It changes the typical declarative order, it indicates [a subject–auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion) is going to take place and the listener is prepared to parse it differently (as a question, perhaps, since it's the most frequent type of inversion in English).

> Could it be ... ?
> Could it be because ... ?
> Could it be because of ... ?

are quite common questions.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways - and the first one is almost conclusive.

1. "Could it be..." is an inverted word order that indicates that a question is being asked (albeit sometimes a rhetorical question).  If it were a simple statement, it would start "It could be".  In a question, the word order is changed: "Could it be".

In rare cases, an inverted order is used for other purposes, such as a hypothetical ("Should it be" can mean "if it should be"/"if it is" - although it is far more frequently used as an interrogative equivalent of "It should be", to ask a question).  But "Could it be" is never used as a hypothetical inversion, only ever as an interrogative inversion.

2. A question normally ends with rising intonation.  A simple statement doesn't tend to (unless perhaps the speaker is looking for confirmation or feeling unsure of themselves), though rising final intonation may be a feature of some dialectal usage and so on.